# How can I print the value of variable y?

Tags: c

I just switched to C from Python and I cannot understand why I cannot print `y` like a normal integer.
For eg if the value of `sum` is greater than `maxsum` when `i=4` I want to print `y` as 4 too. I tried using `i` directly but I was not able to print a normal value.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    int maxsum = 0;
    int list[15];
    int initialindex[15];
    for (int j = 0; j < 15; j++) {
        list[j] = rand() % 300 - 150;
    }
    int sum = 0;
    int count = 0;
    int y = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
        count += 1;
        if (sum + list[i] <= 0) {
            initialindex[i] = -1;
            sum = 0;
        } else if (i != 0 && initialindex[i - 1] != -1) {
            initialindex[i] = initialindex[i - 1];
            sum += list[i];
        } else {
            initialindex[i] = i;
            sum = list[i];
        }
        if (sum > maxsum) {
            maxsum = sum;
            y = count - 1;
        }
        printf("Max is: %d and y is:%d", maxsum, y);
        printf("%d\n", sum);
    }
}
```

Comment: What does "_I was not able to print a normal value_" mean? Does the above program work or not? Unrelated: You may want to put a space or newline before printing `sum` or else `y` and `sum` will look like there is only one number.

Comment: Show your output and show desired output. That would help us a lot.

Comment: `y` and `sum` will be concatenated so you will see them as a single value - try adding a space or a newline (`\n`) to separate them.

Comment: @TedLyngmo ups. Forgot that main returns `0`.

Comment: @Laghari: you can accept an answer by clicking on the grey checkmark below its score.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code works fine, you just forgot a newline at the end of the first `printf` so the value of `y` and `sum` are concatenated on the terminal:

```
// original
printf("Max is: %d and y is:%d",maxsum,y);
printf("%d\n",sum);

// corrected
printf("Max is: %d and y is:%d\n",maxsum,y);
printf("Sum is: %d\n",sum);
```

Answer (score 2):

`printf` does not output an extra newline and you do not print a space or a newline after `y`, hence the digits of `sum` appear immediately after those of `y`.

Modify the code as:

```
printf("Max is: %d and y is: %d\n", maxsum, y);
printf("Sum is: %d\n", sum);
```